# How do I set the default settings for the MeasureIt plugin?

Tags: settings

I use the MeasureIt plugin quite heavily, but I have trouble seeing the default font size and color on a high resolution monitor, so I need to change the font size\color every time I start a new file, or I need to squint at the screen.

Is there a way to set the default settings so that every new file I start has them?

Comment: You can set the default startup file from File > Defaults > Save > Startup File, but I don't know whether the settings for Measureit will be saved at the same time.